# Running Excel Line Graph?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet that automatically scores a questionnaire into 10 different subscales in the first worksheet.  What I would like to be able to do is plot each data collection point on a line graph without having to0 much copying and pasting.  I would like it to be automated like the scoring.

Ideally, the situation would look like this.  Open Excel, enter raw data, new subscale scores added to line graph on that date.  Save.  Open another day, overwrite old raw scores with current ones, KEEP the old line graph data point and have the new scores be added as the next in the series.

This might be too complex for Excel, but it would make it much easier for me to track change over time.

Comment: This involves a little bit of VBA in excel. For example after u replace ur old values with new values,  u should b able to click a button in excel to day that a new line graph needs to be plotted.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You've done a great job of explaining what you want, but missed telling us what you've already tried or researched on your own. You can improve your question by clicking the **[edit]** link under the question to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach here is to convert your data to a table (Insert Table on the Insert tab of the ribbon), with headers in the first row and responses in the second. Make the chart using this table as the data source.

Each day, add data to the row beneath the table. The table will expand when it detects a new row, and the chart will expand when it detects the table stretching.